# Javascript - Text Input Attributes

Tags: javascript, events, forms

I need to create a form element

> <input *disabled* type="text" value="Shui Mu Tsinghua" />

which is *disabled* by default. It enables when **onmouseover** occures.

> onmouseover="this.disabled=false;"

And is disabled by **onmouseout**

> onmouseout="this.disabled=true;"

---

What I need is to check the following.
If the <input> is focused then it shouldn't be disabled.

And if the form element loses focus it disables.

Please help me to complete the events.

<input disabled type="text" value="Shui Mu Tsinghua" onmouseover="this.disabled=false;" onfocus="**???**" onblur="**???**" onmouseout="if(**???**){this.disabled=true;}" />

Comment: That sounds like a very strange user experience, if you don't mind my saying. For one thing, it means you're completely disabling keyboard access to that field. We keyboard types aren't going to like that much, and accessibility software will probably stumble on it as well.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about why you want this behavior?

Comment: I agree with T.J. on that, I seldom touch my mouse on webpages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work, as `onmouseover` does not fire on disabled inputs, in most browsers. (Opera is an exception, and IE usually doesn't, except when you trick it with a drag operation.)

In any case it sounds like a pretty weird and user-unfriendly trick to me. *Why* do you want it disabled? If it becomes non-disabled when you try to interact with it there doesn't seem to be any point to it (but plenty of accessibility downside).

If it's just a styling thing, then use styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .weirdinput { color: silver; }
    .weirdinput:hover, .weirdinput:focus { color: black; }
</style>

<input class="weirdinput" value="smth" />
```

However, IE<8 doesn't support `:focus`, and IE<7 doesn't support `:hover` on non-links, so if you need it to work on that you would have to add some scripting, eg. something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .weirdinput { color: silver; }
    .weirdinput:hover, .weirdinput:focus, .weirdhover, .weirdfocus { color: black; }
</style>

<input class="weirdinput" value="smth" />

<!--[if lt IE 8]><script type="text/javascript">(function() {

    // Fix focus/hover for IE on all inputs with class 'weirdinput'
    //
    var inputs= document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i= 0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        var input= inputs[i];
        if (input.className.indexOf('weirdinput')!==-1) {
            input.onmouseover= mouseover;
            input.onmouseout= mouseout;
            input.onfocus= focus;
            input.onblur= blur;
        }
    }

    function mouseover() {
        this.className+= ' weirdhover';
    }
    function mouseout() {
        this.className= this.className.replace(' weirdhover', '');
    }
    function focus() {
        this.className+= ' weirdfocus';
    }
    function blur() {
        this.className= this.className.replace(' weirdfocus', '');
    }

})();</script><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is;

1. on focus set a variable to true;
2. on blur set the variable to false; and disabled true
3. onmouseover set disabled to false if it is on true
4. onmouseout set disabled ONLY IF variable is false; (so not focussed)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have a lot of trouble getting this behavior, because a disabled field won't receive the `mouseover` (or `mouseenter`, if your browser supports it) event. I even tried capturing the event on an element underneath it, but the disabled field eats it.

Comment: It doesn't? I did not know that, learn something new every day. Maybe he can use readonly instead of disabled if he really wants this kind of functionality..

Comment: @CharlesLeaf: I didn't either. :-) I was curious and tried it.

Answer (score 0):

disabled fields are not submitted, are not in the key tabbing node list, and do not listen to or pass on events. You disable an input so that the user **cannot** change its value.

No field can be changed without first getting the focus.

you can only change the disabled attribute through a script, which would come from an event somewhere else on the page.

But without a name, as in your example, the field's value will not be submitted with its form in any event, so how can it matter that the field is disabled or not?

If your intent is to disable the field if javascript is **not** enabled, why not just hide it with css and show it with a scripted style?